# Why does the CreateWindow() function want the WindowClass's name member and not a pointer to the class itself?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm reading Luna's Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11. Having always programmed for the Linux command line, I decided to start by reading Appendix A, a win32 programming primer, and I don't understand a certain behavior of the CreateWindow() function. Its first parameter is the name of the window class you want to create - so you first have to declare a window class, then "register" it (which I assume means adding the class to some class stack somewhere in the mysterious win32 API), and then you pass the window class's lpszClassName member to the function, like this:

```
WNDCLASS wc;
//set all the various members of wc
wc.lpszClassName = L"BasicWndClass";
RegisterClass(&wc);
ghMainWindow = CreateWindow(L"BasicWndClass", L"LOL", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, instanceHandle, 0);
```

I don't understand why the last line isn't something along the lines of

```
ghMainWindow = CreateWindow(&wc, L"LOL", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, instanceHandle, 0);
```

**Is there some historical or practical reason I'm not aware of?**

EDIT: Also, is it bad practice to do something like this?

```
ghMainWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, L"LOL", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, instanceHandle, 0);
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you don't really care about fighting with OS-specific window creation issues, I recommend something like SDL2 for cross-platform basics.. so you can get on to the interesting bits.

Comment: You get an `ATOM` when you register your class. You can use that if you prefer. The built in classes are registered for you. You refer to them by name. You don't register them.

Comment: Regarding the edit: If you both register a window class and create a window of that class (as is common with an application's main window), you can reuse the `WNDCLASS`s *lpszClassName* member. Another common pattern is to define a named constant (e.g. `const TCHAR g_BasicWnd[] = _T("BasicWndClass");`) and use that constant both for registering the window class and creating the window.

Comment: "*you pass the window class's lpszClassName member to the function*" - no, you pass the *value* of the member, not the member itself. It just happens that sometimes people store the `WNDCLASS` instance in global memory, in which case the `lpszClassName` becomes available to be passed as-is. But `CreateWindow/Ex()` does not know that, or care. It only cares about the *value* of the string being passed to it, and then it looks up that value in the table of registered classes. The memory allocated for the value can come from anywhere, as long as the content of its characters matches.

Comment: A better question is: "why do you have to go to the trouble to register a window class to get an `ATOM`, and then `CreateWindow` wants the original string **rather than the `ATOM` it was reduced to**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the CreateWindow and the RegisterClass calls are generally not in the same module.  CreateWindow is an application-level call, RegisterClass is a library-level call.  The canonical examples are the "Edit" and "Listbox" classes, buried inside the OS.  Using a string or an atom is a very simple way to avoid having to rely on a implementation dependent structure.

Compare WNDCLASS vs WNDCLASSEX to see why that's a good idea.

Comment: Thanks! So this means that if CreateWindow() worked with a pointer to the WNDCLASS it would create problems because WNDCLASS could have different implementations in the app and the API?

Answer (score 0):

RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx return an ATOM that Window's uses internally.  So what you are passing on is an internal reference to that ATOM in the name, also you can create multiple similar windows without having to re-do the RegisterClass part.  Sometimes, people also do the RegisterClass and CreateWindow(Ex) calls in different parts of the code.

Your edited question about using wc.lpszClassName is technically fine, if you change the name in the WNDCLASS section, you won't have issues, though I use an std::string, and assign that to wc.lpszClassName = string.c_str(); then CreateWindow(string.c_str(), ... );

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Using a `std::string` has no advantage over a constant character array, when the only operation you call on it is `c_str()`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of passing around char*'s or any other naked pointers in this day and age of better methods.  As Hans Passant pointed out, a lot of times both are not used in the same place, so it has to be passed.  YMMV but I prefer to show safe code always.

Comment: I wasn't promoting to pass pointers around. I was explicitly talking about arrays. Blindly using `std::string` and calling it safe, just because it's presumably safe, doesn't help. And it suddenly turns completely unsafe, when calling [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx), for example.